# Kafka: What is new API for ConsumerConnector in version 0.11

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm updating Kafka client from `0.8.2.0` to `0.11.0.0`.

In my old code, I use `ConsumerConnector` to get a message stream with the `createMessageStreams` method, and then iterate though the stream for each topic. However, it seems that `ConsumerConnector` has been depreciated in new API.

```
package kafka.consumer

import ...
/**
 *  Main interface for consumer
 */
@deprecated("This trait has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.", "0.11.0.0")
trait ConsumerConnector {
   ...
   def createMessageStreams[K,V](topicCountMap: Map[String,Int],
                                keyDecoder: Decoder[K],
                                valueDecoder: Decoder[V]): Map[String,List[KafkaStream[K,V]]]
   ...
}
```

I looked up the new API and found two candidate:

- `Client API` in org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer
- `Stream API` in org.apache.kafka.streams

Which one should I use? And, how can I achieve the same thing in the new Kafka API?

Answer (score 1):

An example of new consumer is as below:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("group.id", "test");
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"));
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
}
```

See https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html for further details.

Comment: So, in the latest API I need to regularly `poll`, instead of creating a `stream`? If I have a `stream`, Kafka will keep sending me records, so that I don't need to do constantly polling. Is there a way to do it in the latest API or is there a reason to use your way instead?